# getting empty object while sending formData

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying to upload an image and then send it to the server. But turns out I'm sending an empty object to the server. I'm not using any form. Just through input tag. Is the code correct?

html:

```
 <div>
    <input type="file" class="fileUpload" name="file"/>
 </div>
```

js:

```
 document.querySelector('.fileUpload').addEventListener("change", function(e){

       let formData = new FormData();
       formData.append('imageFiles', e.target.files[0])



     // for(var v of formData) {
     //   console.log(v[0]+', '+v[1]);
     // } i tried to check here and it gives `imageFiles, [object File]`. This made me 
      // think there is data so sent it to server.
       

       fetch(`/image`, {
         method: 'POST',
         headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
         body: JSON.stringify(formData)
        }).then(res => console.log(res))
        .then(json => console.log(json))
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
  })
```

node.js:

```
 app.post('/image', (req, resp) => {

  console.log(req.body)// but get empty object on server {}

})
```

Comment: You can't JSON.stringify a FormData object.

Comment: you have to use third party packages like `multer`  with routes and follow above comment also.

Comment: @Quentin: If I don't use stringify, then i get `unexpected token error.`

Comment: Where do you get this unexpected token error?

Comment: on the server i get `Unexpected token - in JSON at position 0` if i send `body: formData`. or i get unxpected token error on clientside if i do  `body: JSON.parse(formData)`

Comment: @Deke — Well. It isn't JSON. Did you continue to claim `{ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }` even after you stopped trying to convert the formdata object to JSON? Did you read the duplicate linked from the massive blue box at the top of the page?

Comment: Hold on. I'm trying. I'll get back to you once i'm done. i read it just now.

Comment: i got it! removed the content type, removed strigify and used multer on server to get the formdata